# javascript scroll separate jScrollpane

Tags: javascript, web, jscrollpane

On my webpage I use jScrollpane for some content, and I have a menu bar outside of the scrollpane on the left side. Currently I use internal anchor links from the menu bar to link to specific places in the content, and by setting the jscrollpane hijackInternallinks option to 'true', this would make the scrollpane scroll to the right place. However, I was wondering if there was a way to do this without using internal links? Is there a way to do this with just javascript, where I bind a click function to the menu items which, when clicked, will also cause the jscrollpane to scroll to the place that I want it to in the content?